# Search in ArrayList and count

Tags: java, arraylist

In this code I want to search in an `ArrayList` but my code returns an incorrect result and I can not resolve this problem.

`ReceivedItemStructure` structure:

```
public class ReceivedItemStructure {
    public String mLastID;
    public String mUserID;
    public String mSmsBody;
    public String mMobileNumber;
    public String mDate;
    public String mSenderName;
    public String mSmsNumber;
    public String mContactName;

public String getmLastID() {
        return mLastID;
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
int countSMS = 0;

String smsReceivedSender = "";
String r = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, 0, 20, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();

JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(r);

for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);
    String mId = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");

    for (ReceivedItemStructure rf:items){

        if( ! mId.equals(rf.getmLastID()) ) {
            countSMS++;
        }
    }

}
```

My problem is this line :

```
if( ! mId.equals(rf.getmLastID()) ) {
```

if `mId = 2000` and `rf.getmLastID() = 1000` then `count` must be `++`

Comment: what do you want to count exactly? and what is in your `items` List?

Comment: What is your result?

Comment: @NIPHIN `if` statement dont plus `countSMS`

Comment: @A.S. please see exactly my code. `items` is `ReceivedItemStructure`

Comment: I do not see where the `items` are filled, think you do iterate over a empty list, just try to log every iteration in your foreach

Comment: @A.S. items is `items = new ArrayList<ReceivedItemStructure>();` and thats not empty

Comment: so it is empty, you are trying to iterate over a empty list

Comment: @A.S. not empty . i have any data into that and i want to search into `items`

Comment: @A.S. see this link: http://pastebin.com/NB5dt3gn

Comment: please see my answer and post your whole logcat output, are you sure you want to count the values that do not match?

Comment: @A.S. please see full LogCat : http://pastebin.com/JE5tTUFf

Comment: why are you now comparing your objects not the id strings? Do you have Overriden the equals?

Comment: And what exactly you are tring to count, the equal objects or the not equal objects, if you do want to count the equal objects leave the `!` in your if statement

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java search array key value with data in class structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251353/java-search-array-key-value-with-data-in-class-structure)

Answer (score 1):

Loop through your list and do a `contains` or `startswith`.

```
ArrayList<String> resList = new ArrayList<String>();
String searchString = "man";

for (String curVal : list){
  if (curVal.contains(searchString)){
    resList.add(curVal);
  }
}
```

You can wrap that in a method. The contains checks if its in the list. You could also go for startswith.

Comment: `contains` does not work in class structure like my class `ReceivedItemStructure`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so to clarify please try to debug your code like this:

```
int countSMS = 0;

String TAG = "Debugger";

String smsReceivedSender = "";
String r = new JsonService(config_username, config_password, 0, 20, G.F_RECEIVE_SMS).request();

JSONArray data_array = new JSONArray(r);
Log.i(TAG, "items size is " + items.size());

for (int i = 0; i < data_array.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject json_obj = data_array.getJSONObject(i);
    String mId = json_obj.getString("id_recived_sms");
    Log.i(TAG, "Trying to compare " + mId);
    for (ReceivedItemStructure rf:items){
        Log.i(TAG, "iteration step of  " + rf.getmLastID);
        if( ! mId.equals(rf.getmLastID()) ) {

            countSMS++;
            Log.i(TAG, "they are equal, count is " + countSMS);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: So this is the correct behaviour, what exactly do you want to count? please tell me.

Comment: for example i have `30354260` in `mId` and thats not into `ReceivedItemStructure` then that must be Log for me `found` but thats could not find and `if` dont work corectly.

Comment: So why not count the matches and make a subtraction from the size?